# Do no not want Zend Framework View's short tag. Is there an alternative to $view->setUseStreamWrapper(true)?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to learn the Zend Framework, my first framework, and I came across the View section. In order to out put stuff from the controller to the view, I have to use short tags. I don't want to do this because of XML. The only option, I've found so far, is `$view->setUseStreamWrapper(true)` which apparently kills performance. I was wondering if there is any alternative solutions (other than `$view->setUseStreamWrapper(true)`)?

Thank you in advance.

Sorry here's a clarification:

```
application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml

`Escape($this->name);?> from Zend Framework
```

Instead of `<?=$this->Escape($this->name);?>`, I want to  use the long tags `<?php=` $this->Escape($this->name);?>. But it doesn't seem to work. Zend framework forces us to use short tags no?

Comment: `<?= $this->Escape($this->name);?>` equals to `<?php echo $this->Escape($this->name); ?>` (notice there is echo statement instead of `=` character *and* space.

Comment: And ZF does not force anything. You are free to use anything you wish. Stream wrappers do not have performance impact when you use cache.

Comment: I use view helper for XML declaration (like doctype one). Then used short tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking, but you do not have to use short tags, you can use long ones.  You can also use short tags without using `$view->setUseStreamWrapper(true)`, you simply need to turn on short tags in your php.ini (you may also be able to set it in your script, but I am not sure)  I believe all `$view->setUseStreamWrapper(true)` does is pre parse your script and turn `<?` into `<?php`.
As for performance degradation, it was my experience that the ZF was slow no matter what you do. It seems the Zend people put a TON of stuff in the framework that has no business being in there, it seems that it is just a huge beast that tries to do everything, and so it end up doing it all poorly. Could just be me though.

Comment: I'm asking if instead of using the short tags in the view files can I use the long tags instead? Instead of using <?= I wanted to use <?php= but it doesn't seem to work for the view files.

<code>
application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml
<head>
<title>Hello Zend</title>
</head>
<pre>
<h1>Hello Zend</h1>
<p>Hello <?=$this->Escape($this->name);?> from Zend Framework</p>
</body>
</pre>

Comment: Using long is perfectly fine, coding practice at the job I had with the ZF did not allow for short tags.  But I don't believe <?php= is a valid tag, you would have to use <?php echo perhaps that is your problem?

Comment: That's my problem it's the echo -_-;; Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
<?php echo $this->escape($this->name); ?>
```

or if you want to use short tags, you can set it on most servers in your .htaccess

```
php_value "short_open_tag" "on"
```

Comment: Ah but using long tags doesn't seem to work with Zend View files. I've tried it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the `<?` Then no, you don't **have to** use them, you can use them. Just use `<?php` instead.
I do not see how `$view->setUseStreamWrapper` is connected to the question.

```
<?=
```

will translate to

```
<?php echo
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use the long tags Escape($this->name);?>

This is not long nor valid tag. There is no such syntax in PHP
If you want to use long tags, you have to make it

```
<?php echo  $this->Escape($this->name);?>
```